# com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'C' of null

Tags: java, gwt, html-parsing

I have defined the following custom tag `<custlib:mytag myttribute="myval"/>`

While I execute this gwt app and try to process the custlib:mytag it works fine in hosted dev mode.. where as in the web mode I get the following exception

```
Thu Mar 27 12:11:19 GMT+530 2014 HTMLPROCESSOR SEVERE: processor excep
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'C' of null
   at Unknown.Dn(StackTraceCreator.java:168)
   at Unknown.Em(StackTraceCreator.java:421)
   at Unknown.ES(Exceptions.java:29)
   at Unknown.ci(UIObject.java:528)
   at Unknown.ai(HTMLPanel.java:183)
   at Unknown.lh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:179)
   at Unknown.mh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:91)
   at Unknown.mh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:81)
   at Unknown.mh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:81)
   at Unknown.mh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:81)
   at Unknown.mh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:81)
   at Unknown.mh(HtmlPageProcessor.java:81)
   at Unknown.bb(HtmlPageProcessor.java:37)
   at Unknown.DS(Stats.java:28)
   at Unknown._m(Impl.java:168)
   at Unknown.cn(Impl.java:220)
   at Unknown.anonymous(Impl.java:57)
   at Unknown.gwtOnLoad(com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.GenerateJavaScriptAST:0)
Thu Mar 27 12:11:19 GMT+530 2014 HTMLPROCESSOR SEVERE: processor excep
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): Cannot read property 'C' of null
```

What could be the issue.. ?

Any help would be appreciated. .

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I have a similar one in web mode, but in dev mode it works fine.